# Open SDP File in .Net C#

Tags: c#, http, stream, mjpeg, sdp

I'm developing a C#’s application with the ability to view an MJPEG encoded video stream, from an encoder (Teleste MPX-E8).

I can see a stream through the Encoder’s Video Encoding Settings page, and I’ve read the stream is encapsulated in an SDP file.

So, into my C# application, I’ve tried to implement the SDP protocol, but the only documentations / examples I found all relates to SIP protocol.

With Wireshark, I can see that when I made an HTTP request to the encoder, it responds with a 200 OK, and SDP.
I suppose that I need to send an acknowledge to my encoder to receive stream, but I can't figure out how to send it.

Does anyone can help me ?!

Thanks in advance for your response !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SDPLib](https://github.com/tvildo/SDPLib) Session Description Protocol library library to read SDP file

Answer (score 0):

The video encoder implements `RTSP` protocol, SDP is a part of it that describes details of video feed. The RTSP configuration is set up on the device, see [P6I_MPX_E.pdf](http://www.teleste.com/ProductDocument/P6I_MPX_E.pdf) page 45, and remotely you connect with RTSP client software, such as [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

In C# you need a library that implements RTSP client - it will do all networking you need and delvier you JPEG frames from the device, either compressed or already decoded. You will present the frames on the application UI.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Now, I've been looking for some code / library that implements RTSP client in C#, but haven't found anything.

All results are talking about RTSP Server, or people said to use VLC or other, but in my case, I really need to have a C# decoder.

Answer (score 0):

https://net7mma.codeplex.com/ Does Sdp..

It also contains a RtspClient and RtspServer all in pure C#

There is an article here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Let me know if you need anything else!